# check if PIE is enable in python

Tags: python, file, elf

Here since yesterday I look at how to detect if the protection "PIE" is activated. For that I analyzed the output of the relocation entries to see if **_ITM_deregisterTMClone** is present or not. Is there a better way to detect PIE without going through a readelf output?

Here is what I currently have :

```
def display_pie(counter):
    if (counter == 1):
            print("Pie : Enable")
    else:
            print("Pie: No PIE")

def check_file_pie(data_file):
    data = []
    data2 = []
    result = []
    ctn = 0
    check = subprocess.Popen(["readelf", "-r", data_file],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = check.stdout.readlines()
    for x in result:
        data.append(list(x))
    for lines in data:
            data2.append("".join(map(chr, lines)))
    for new_lines in data2:
            if "_ITM_deregisterTMClone" in new_lines:
                    ctn += 1
    display_pie(ctn)
```

Thank you it's quite technical so if someone can explain me a better way to check the Executable Independent Position, I'm interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pyelftools](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools) to check if the ELF is a shared object and if the image base address is zero:

```
def is_pie(filename):
    from elftools.elf.elffile import ELFFile
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        elffile = ELFFile(file)
        base_address = next(seg for seg in elffile.iter_segments() if seg['p_type'] == "PT_LOAD")['p_vaddr']
        return elffile.elftype == 'DYN' and base_address == 0
```

Comment: thanks, why look at this basic address? I have this error '' ELFFile 'object has no attribute' segments ''

Comment: I edit the code to work on the latest `pyelftools`. The check for a non-zero base is because of this: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/426253/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pwntools](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/), which has [functionality for manipulating ELF files](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/elf/elf.html#pwnlib.elf.elf.ELF.pie). Example usage:

```
>>> from pwn import *
>>> e = ELF('your-elf-file')
>>> e.pie
True
```

If you want to know how it is implemented, you can [find the source code here](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/blob/292b81af17/pwnlib/elf/elf.py#L1494).

Comment: yes I know this tools well I can even find it with radare2 if I want but my goal to ask for a better method of implementation of what I did above and explain to me precisely what are things added when this PIE.